# Magento 2 assets trying to load over https

Tags: magento2

I have a weird issue whereby assets are loading over https on my local environment and so cannot be found.

The reference to the asset when I view the source is on http:// but when I check the console it appears they're loading over https:// and giving the error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The base_urls are set to http so I'm not sure why it's loading them over https

Does any one have any ideas why?

Cheers

Comment: This solution work for you?

Answer (score 3):

This issue might because of your below admin setting.

**Login to Admin Panel** and Head to **Admin > System > Configuration > General > Web**.

Here check below setting

Check **Use Secure URL for frontend option**. If here is **YES** Then make it **NO**

Same for the admin Check **Use Secure URLs in Admin**. If here is **YES** Then make it **NO**

See below screenshot.

[image]

Also check base Secure URL in Unsecured URL setting in admin and inside **core_config_data** database table.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `core_config_date` find `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` update value from `1` to `0`.

Run the cache clean command.

`php bin/magento cache:clean`